Microsoft Store>Visual Studio 2022>Install>Show details>Show information about publisher's certificate shows: "Valid from 12/15/2020 to 12/2/2021"
Microsoft Store>Visual Studio 2022>Install>Show details>Show information about publisher's certificate shows:
"Issued by: Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010"
"Valid from 12/15/2020 to 12/2/2021".
But it is now 2024. Install this?
Since Microsoft had breaches in the past -- due to use of outdated algorithms (such as MD5) for Windows Update -- am scared to install this unless it shows valid through 2024.
Microsoft Copilot says that those values are not normal for Microsoft Store and to contact Microsoft Support, but was not able to.
This was on Windows 10 with the included Microsoft Store. Windows Update says no updates available.

Is this a "certificate replay attack", or did Microsoft just mess up the upload of Microsoft Visual?
